# Postgres sort expression

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with goods:

```
CREATE TABLE public.goods (
    "id" bigserial NOT NULL,
     title varchar(250) NOT NULL,
     cost numeric(10,2),
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

Now I want to sort this table by title but put all goods with cost 0 at the end of the list. Is this possible?
If I try to use:

```
ORDER BY
    cost DESC,
    title ASC
```

I get incorrect order by title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a `CASE` expression when ordering which places the block of records having a zero cost at the bottom.  Then, within each block (either zero cost or non-zero cost), the records can be sorted alphabetically by the title.

```
SELECT cost, title
FROM public.goods
ORDER BY CASE WHEN cost = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         title
```